# Ubuntu 14.04.03 wont accept password password is correct

Tags: password

Ubuntu 14.04.03 i set up my user name and password installation finishes
i reboot type in the username and password says it incorrect password
but it is definitely the correct password.

Comment: Can you login to the terminal Ctl+Alt+F3

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you check your keyboard configuration setting. Maybe you are using a different keyboard configuration than when you created the account and the password you type end up being different. For exemple, "Canadian french" keyboard or "English Canada" keyboard.

It's not really possible for a password to change on it's own so unless there's a problem with the installation I suggest checking keyboard configuration or something like CAPS lock.

itSp4x